# C# Xamarin.forms ListView population listview with list<string>

Tags: c#, string, listview, xamarin.forms

I am trying to parse a string of events into a list EventsList, then populate the fields in my listview (title, location, time, and date) with the correct strings from EventList. 
The problem I have run into now is that the method used to populate EventsList is returning something that is no where to be found in my string. The string displayed from EventsList is:

System.Collections.GenericList'1[System.String]

If anyone could help me figure out why it is returning that it would be much appreciated - or if there is a better strategy to do this please enlighten me.

```
           List<string> EventsList = new List<string>();
        EventsList = EventDetails(EventsList);

        List<string> EventDetails(List<string> arEvents)
        {
            int indexNum = 67;
            string events = GetEvents();


            //while (indexNum <= 78)
            //{
                int index1 = (events.IndexOf(indexNum.ToString())) + 2;
                int commaIndex = events.IndexOf(",");
                if ((commaIndex - index1) <= 0)
                {
                    string Title = events.Substring(index1, 10);
                    indexNum++;
                }
                else
                indexNum++;
            // }
            Title = events.Substring(index1, 10);
            arEvents.Add(Title);
            return arEvents;
        }

            MainListView.ItemsSource = new List<APBEvent>
        {
            new APBEvent()
            {
              EventTitle = GetEvents(),
              EventLocation = "line break",
              EventTime = EventsList.ToString(),
              EventDate = "5/11/18",
            },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EventsList.ToString()
```

EventList is `list<string>` and you can not convert `list` to `string`.

If you want to convert `list<string>` contents to `string` then you can join the contents by using `string.join`

```
string.join(",",EventList);
```